# PHP - Internal Server Error using php-gd

Tags: php, php-gd

When I use some function like `imagecreate()` or `imagecreatefromjpeg()` the result that I get is an internal server error.

The code is the following:

```
<?php

$width = 520;
$height = 360;

$image = imagecreate($width, $height);

?>
```

The version I'm using is `php 7.2`. I've tried to install the following package:

```
apt-get install php7.2-gd
```

Thanks.

Comment: check your (error) logs.

Comment: show us error page

Comment: Like the people that already commented. Please post your error page(s), error logs, and if possible if you're using a framework, a stacktrace.

Comment: Put error_reporting(E_ALL|E_NOTICE); after the `<?php ` - tag

Comment: Even if you installed the `gd` package, did you also activate the extension?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP's white screen of death](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death)

Comment: I'm sorry the gd extension was not activated. Thanks for the help.